# How to execute this javascript code without eval()?

Tags: javascript, eval

```
function run(conditions) {
/* --- code --- */
var pages_counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('onload_counter'));
var seconds_counter = parseInt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("waiting_for_modal"))[0])+1;
/* --- code --- */
var vared = eval(conditions.test.join(' ')) ? true:false;
if(vared){
jQuery('#myid').fadeOut(500);
}
}

var conditions = {
/* --- code --- */
"test": ["( pages_counter > 1 && seconds_counter > 10 )||( seconds_counter > 40 && pages_counter === 1 )"]
};
run(conditions);
```

Is eval() dangerous in this case? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could pass the numbers, i.e.g., `1`, `10`, `40`, `1` instead of also passing the variable names

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a function for it?

```
var conditions = {          
    test: function (pages_counter, seconds_counter) {
        return (pages_counter > 1 && seconds_counter > 10) || (seconds_counter > 40 && pages_counter === 1);
    }
};

// test with
var vared = conditions.test(pages_counter, seconds_counter);
```

Comment: @Nina_Scholz , ReferenceError: onload_counter is not defined

Comment: so have a look where `onload_counter` is defined or used. i can not help without more knowledge about the rest of your code.